# Is cookie a common and secure implementation of session?

Tags: python, session, cookies, pyramid

I'm using pyramid web framework. I was confused by the relationship between the cookie and session. After looked up in wikipedia, did I know that session is an abstract concept and cookie may just be an kind of approach (on the client side).

So, my question is, what's the most common implementation (on both the client and server)? Can somebody give some example (maybe just description) codes? (**I wouldn't like to use the provided session support inside the pyramid in order to learn**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the cookie stored with the client is just a long, hard-to-guess hash code string that can be used as a key into a database. On the server side, you have a table mapping those session hashes to primary keys (a session hash should *never* be a primary key) and expiration timestamps.

So when you get a request, first thing you do is look for the cookie. If there isn't one, create a session entry (cookie + expiration timestamp) in the database table. If there is one, look it up and make sure it hasn't expired; if it has, make a new one. In either case, if you made a new cookie, you might want to pass that fact down to later code so it knows if it needs to ask for a login or something. If you didn't need to make a new cookie, reset the expiration timestamp so you don't expire the session too soon.

While handling the view code and generating a response, you can use that session primary key to index into other tables that have data associated with the session. Finally, in the response sent back to the client, set the cookie to the session key hash.

If someone has cookies disabled, then their session cookie will always be new, and any session-based features won't work.

Comment: The description is in detail. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

The most common implementation of sessions is to use a cookie.

A cookie provides a way to store an arbitrary piece of text, which is usually used as a session identifier. When the cookie gets sent along with a HTTP request, the server (technically the code running on it) can use the cookie text (if it exists) to recognise that it has seen a client before. Text in a cookie usually provides enough information to retrieve extra information from the database about this client.

For example, a very naive implementation might store the primary key to the `shopping_cart` table in a database, so that when the server receives the cookie text it can directly use it to access the appropriate shopping cart for that particular client.

(And it's a naive approach because a user can do something like change their own cookie to a different primary key and access someone else's cart that way. Choosing a proper session id [isn't as simple as it seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_theft_and_session_hijacking), which is why it's almost always better to use an existing implementation of sessions.)

An alternate approach is to store a session identifier is to use a GET parameter in the url (for example, in something like `http://example.com/some/page?sid=4s6da4sdasd48`, then the `sid` GET param serves the same function as the cookie string). In this approach, all links to other pages on the site have the GET param appended to them.

Comment: Thx for the hint `isn't as simple as it seems`

Answer (score 1):

A session is (usually) a cookie that has a unique value. This value maps to a value in a database or held in memory that then tells you what session to load. PHP has an alternate method where it appends a unique value to the end of every URL (if you've ever seen PHPSESSID in a URL you now know why) but that has security implications (in theory).

Of course, since cookies are sent back and forth with every request unless you're talking over HTTPS you are sending the only way to know (reliably) that the client you are talking to now is the same one you logged in ten seconds ago to anyone on the same wireless network. See programs like Firesheep for reasons why switching to HTTPS is a good idea.

Finally, if you do want to build your own I, was given some advice on the matter by a university professor. Give out a new token on every page load and invalidate all a users tokens if an invalid token is used. This just means that if an attacker does get a token and logs in to it whilst it is still valid when the victim clicks a link both parties get logged out.

Comment: Re: unique tokens: looking at the tokens, you could also surmise that the user used the back button and resubmitted a form.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Surely if the user presses the back button their cookie state is not reversed to the state it had been at that page? Can you provide any evidence to say it does?

Comment: No, but the other fields (including hidden fields) on that page are reversed to what they were. So if the token value is a hidden form field, the fact that it doesn't match the token in the cookie tells you something.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I was told that the cookie value should be stored server side and not stored as a hidden value in a form, as an attacker who had stolen the cookie could then presumably modify the hidden value and pass themselves off as a valid session.

Comment: Please reread my answer. **Of course** you store the cookie server-side. The only reason to put it in a form is if you are changing the cookie's value with every page load. This way you can compare the hidden field value with the server-side value, and if they differ, you know the user submitted an old form. I have no idea if you care that an old form was submitted; in the case of POST (as opposed to GET) forms, this might matter so something doesn't get done twice. But that's up to the developer to determine.